# I want to create a route in Remix Run, without URL nesting or Layout Nesting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

How do you create a link like `xx.com/blog` and have it load from a different file
without keeping it in the `routes` folder

if you have unwanted layout defined in `app/root.tsx` and `app/routes/index.tsx`

I tried the method of using dot notation

- such as `root.blog.tsx` and `app.blog.tsx` and ```app.index.tsx

where I kept the file `blog.tsx` or `index.tsx` in `routes/blog/`

I tried creating a special URL from `remix.config.tsx` but it didn't remove the `layout`

Comment: Can you create a simple repo with what you've tried? Where is the route file you want to load, if not in the routes folder?

Answer (score -1):

All routes should be in the routes folder to generate them automatically.

If your only goal is to have the url appear at a particular level, but without using nested layouts (or using a different layout), you can use the [Pathless Layout Routes](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/routing#pathless-layout-routes).

```
routes/__blog.tsx (this is the root layout for your blog page
routes/__blog/blog.tsx (this is the actual page for your blog)
```

this will produce domain.com/blog, it will load the Page defined in `__blog/blog.tsx` and load it in the `<Outlet />` defined in the `__blog.tsx`

To take another example, let's say you are a SaaS website, and you have your marketing routes:

```
domain.com/pricing
domain.com/features
domain.com/signup
```

and then you have your actual application, but you don't want a different subdomain or sub route:

```
domain.com/dashboard
domain.com/profile
domain.com/billing
```

The marketing pages all have the marketing layout (so nice header, footer, etc) the "app" routes are all a side bar shell with no footer. This can be achieved like so:

```
routes/__marketing.tsx (Layout)
routes/__dashboard.tsx (Layout)
routes/__marketing/pricing.tsx (Page)
routes/__marketing/features.tsx (Page)
routes/__marketing/signup.tsx (Page)
routes/__dashboard/dashboard.tsx (Page)
routes/__dashboard/profile.tsx (Page)
routes/__dashboard/billing.tsx (Page)
```

This would produce the routes mentioned above, but some would use the __marketing layout and some would use the __dashboard layout.

If this is not your use case, and you really do want to just load a page from somewhere other than your routes/ folder, you can define *only* a loader in your route, the loader can grab whatever it needs from wherever it needs and then return an html/text (or whatever you want) content type with the content. This way there is no page, just think of it like an api route that renders something.

However if your use case is just different layouts for same-level route paths, the dunder method is the way to go.

Comment: "the loader can grab whatever it needs from wherever it needs and then return an html/text" -- But in my case, I can not get rid of the layout. Even tho I get a new html, it is render inside the layout. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Double underscore does not work for me, and I cannot find the official docs for this.